# Use asyncio.all_tasks() in the right place

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am reading the book and face the code snippet, which doesn't makes sense for me. Can someone clarify that for me ?

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    print(f'{time.ctime()} Hello!')
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    print(f'{time.ctime()} Goodbye!')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(main())
loop.run_until_complete(task) # This line is responsible to block the thread (Which is MainThread in my case), until every coroutine won't be finished.
pending = asyncio.all_tasks(loop=loop) # asyncio.all_tasks() Return a set of not yet finished Task objects run by the loop. Based on definition, pending will always be an empty set.
for task in pending:
    task.cancel()
group = asyncio.gather(*pending, return_exceptions=True)
loop.run_until_complete(group)
loop.close()
```

I think `asyncio.all_tasks()` should be used before `loop.run_until_complete()` function. Besides I find many other places where it is useful, but this example absolutely does not makes sense for me. I am really interested in, why author did that ? What was the point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are thinking is correct. There is no point here for having `.all_tasks()` as it always returns an empty set. You only have one task and you pass it to `.run_until_complete()`, so it blocks until it gets done.

But things change when you have another task that takes longer than your `main` coroutine:

```py
import asyncio
import time


async def longer_task():
    print("inside longer coroutine")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)


async def main():
    print(f"{time.ctime()} Hello!")
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    print(f"{time.ctime()} Goodbye!")


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
task1 = loop.create_task(main())
task2 = loop.create_task(longer_task())

loop.run_until_complete(task1)

pending = asyncio.all_tasks(loop=loop)
print(pending)
for task in pending:
    task.cancel()
group = asyncio.gather(*pending, return_exceptions=True)
loop.run_until_complete(group)
loop.close()
```

Event loop only cares to finish `task1` so `task2` is gonna be in pending mode.

> I think asyncio.all_tasks() should be used before
> loop.run_until_complete() function.

As soon as you `create_task()`, it will be included in the set returned by `all_tasks()` even if the loop has not started yet.

Just a side note: (version 3.10) Since you don't have a running event loop, `.get_event_loop()` will warn you. use `.new_event_loop()` instead.